# Painting Vinyl siding?

Tags: painting, vinyl-siding

Has anyone had success or tried painting vinyl siding?  Apparently [Benjamin Moore](http://www2.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-contractors/painting-vinyl-and-aluminum-siding#)
 claims that it is possible but I wanted to know if anyone has done this? Were there any pitfalls or learning?

The reason to want to do this should be pretty obvious as replacing all the siding on a house purely because of color is a lot of money. Basically I have a yellow house, the siding is in good condition, but quite ugly so was hoping there is an effective way to change its color other than buying new.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the link you posted is for the Regal Select Exterior Revive. This product is made specifically for Vinyl Siding. It is designed to be buckle-resistant and no primer is needed. I painted houses professionally for 11 years and all I used were Benjamin Moore products. I have used this on vinyl shutters and it works exceptionally well. Benjamin Moore is expensive, but it covers well and lasts for many years. I would note that yellow is one of the hardest colors to cover in a single coat. You will probably have to double coat it.

[image: Benjamin Moore Revive]

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It is nice to hear that you have personally used it before. Did it have any issues where you could scratch it with your fingernail as I have heard can sometimes be an issue? I would more than likely be going to white from the yellow so at least a lighter color

Comment: Honestly, I never tried to scratch at it. Call your local Benjamin Moore dealer. Sometimes they have a display sample of specialty paint products for you to take a look at.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done but I would leave it. A poor paint job could mess up your siding and a quality paint job might cost just as much as getting the siding replaced. Of course I never advocate to spend money on things that are purely cosmetic.